# Hospital spendings on IT services and infrastructure

Tags: medical, europe, germany, computing, technology

How much do hospitals in the EU spend on Software, IT-consulting and IT-infrastructure (servers and such)? How much in individual countries, Germany being of particular interest?

This is what I tried:

- checking annual reports of publicly listed companies
- checking the NHS website
- Scanning consulting reports from big consultancies
- Reading govt reports on digitalisation in healthcare
- EU initiatives and reports

So far I have not been able to find a reliable source that gives this information. It seems to me like this should be available somewhere, especially as governments are so heavily involved in health-care. Does anybody have an idea how to source this information?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the ONS see stats for 2021 here for example:
https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/healthcaresystem/bulletins/healthcareexpenditureukhealthaccountsprovisionalestimates/2021#healthcare-expenditure-data

Or you could have a look at the statistics from the government.
https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-7281/

As for Germany I imagine this will be difficult as the each of the 16 states might or might not have their own statistics. But you could try the Statistische Bundesamt here for example:
https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Gesellschaft-Umwelt/Gesundheit/Krankenhaeuser/_inhalt.html

Comment: If you are interested in the UK data you might be able to raise a Freedom of Information request if the data does not exist but you would probably have to approach each Trust individually.